# What kind of regression to use for multiple independent variables and multiple treatments

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression

I am brand new to stats and trying to run my first regression based on an existing dataset I've been given at work, and I need some help being pointed in the right direction.  I'm self taught, so apologies in advances as my knowledge and vocab on the topic is very patchy!

In the survey participants have been tested on a topic, and we'd like to look at how their 1) age, 2) preexisting familiarity with the topic, and 3) daily news consumption habits have effected their performance.  Participants were asked yes/no questions, so their responses have been recorded as either 0 (incorrect) or 1 (correct).

We want to asertain the impact of participants' overall performance  based on the three independent variables and controlling for the other two variables when examining each one.  There are also four subtopics (treatments?) within the test we'd also like to individually assess the impact of the three independent variables against as well.

I think should be running a multinomial logistic regression because two of the independent variables are categorical and because I can make age categorical by bucketing it into four age groups.  But how do I analyze three independent variables across multiple 'treatments'/subtopics in one regression? Can I?

I just don't know enough vocabulary to understand what to look up regarding the regression model type and multiple 'treatments' requirement, so I'm a bit stuck.  Any insights or advice on which direct to go would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, the type of regression (OLS, logistic, multinomial, etc.) depends on the dependent variable, not the independent variables.

Second, binning age would almost certainly be a mistake.

Third, which type then depends on how many questions the participants were asked in the "test on a topic" and how those were scored. If they were simply added into a "total number correct" and that number isn't large, then I would look at a count regression model (Possion or, more likely, negative binomial).  If it is a lot of questions then OLS regression might be OK. If you are creating a score through something like factor analysis (although this is tricky with dichotomous questions) then probably OLS regression.

Comment: Thanks Peter! There were 1300 participants and 150 questions in total (90 in subsection 1, 20 in section 2, 20 in section 3, and then 15 in section 4.)  Each question had two option (if they were correct it was coded as a 1, incorrect was a 0).  Performance is determined by averaging out the observations.  There's about 1300 participants, so maybe an OLS regression might be better? From a quick google it looks like I should code the two categorical independent variables (IV) to make them usable in a linear regression, is that it?  What kind of coding should I do in that case?

Comment: With 150 questions, OLS regression should be fine. Any statistics program (R, SAS, SPSS etc) will handle the coding for you.